# Powershell add newest file in directory to existing file

Tags: powershell

I'm getting a strange result when running an add-content command in powershell. here is my code:

```
gci "C:\dir\*.txt" | sort LastWriteTime  | select -last 1 | add-content  "C:\dir2\blah2.txt"
```

When I open up blah2, I am seeing just the filename *.txt

I tried using out-file as well, and got another puzzling (to me) result:

```
Directory: C:\

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
-a---         6/24/2013   4:02 PM        719 00010_06242013_1600.txt
```

Comment: Given that you're sorting the results of the first cmdlet, did you mean to specify an example directory instead of a file?  `blah.txt` seems to indicate a file.

Comment: Good call, edited to reflect that, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume you are attempting to get the contents of "C:\blah.txt" and add that to "C:\blah2.txt"?

At the moment you currently get 1 item ("C:\Blah.txt") then sort it by last write time, then select 1 (there is only ever one), then add the output to "C:\blah2.txt". This will write whatever the regular output is to the file.

If you want to write the **contents** of blah into blah2 you're missing a vital step:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\blah.txt" | sort LastWriteTime  | select -last 1 | Get-Content | add-content  "C:\blah2.txt"
```

After removing redundant calls:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\blah.txt" | Get-Content | add-content  "C:\blah2.txt"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My apologies my original response has been edited to show that I am trying to get the most recent file in a directory and add it to the end of a file in a separate directory.

Comment: So you're trying to get the content of the most recent file in the directory or are you trying to append the file name to a list of file names?

Comment: I want to get the most recent file in a directory and add the contents of that file to a file in a separate directory.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
(gci .\blah.txt).lastwritetime > blah2.txt
```

There are several things i can see in your code:

1. If this is only handle one file, we don't need "sort".
2. "Sort" and "select" don't change object type so what add-content gets is just file name blah.txt from the first command in pipe line "gci "c:\blah.txt". Following is my test to show that, I will do a get-member to both you will see the objects are the same: System.IO.FileInfo.

   PS C:\Documents\ManualScripts> gci .\test.txt |  get-member

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo
   ........

compared to:

```
PS C:\Documents\ManualScripts> gci .\test.txt |  get-member


   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo
......
```

They are exactly the same.

Comment: If it is for adding content from one file to another, you also can use this: `type blah.txt > blah2.txt`.

Comment: If you want it to pick a newest-written file in whole current directory then this is the code: `type $(gci *.* | sort lastwritetime | select -last 1) > blah2.txt`

Comment: Sorry my original question has been edited to show that i want the most recent file in a directory.